# Amortized runtime for insertion in scapegoat tree

Tags: binary-search-tree, insertion, amortized-analysis

I am working on the following problem, from a problem set for a course I am self studying.

[image: Original Problem]

I have solved the first part.  I'm stuck on the second.  These are my thoughts so far.  I think that the proper way to rebuild the subtree rooted at v would be to traverse it once to copy the values into an array in sorted order, and then, traverse it once again to build it into a balanced binary tree.  Thus, this would be linear in v.size.  However, I don't see where the potential and the constant can turn this into a O(1), let alone how such a constant could depend upon alpha.  As I thought the rebuild operation was independent of alpha, and alpha simply affects how often you have to rebuild?  So would the alpha come out of the potential function?  And then the c just serves to cancel the alpha?  If so, could I have some guidance as to how to rewrite the potential function?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rewrite the potential function. The way that c and alpha interact is in the part of (2) in which "a subtree that is not alpha-balanced". That should help you derive a lower bound on the potential of that subtree. Part (1) helps you derive an upper bound on the potential of that subtree after the rebuilding. The resulting difference in potential should help you pay for the rebuilding.

In particular, the lower bound will be something like f(c,alpha) * m for some function f. This problem wants you to find an expression for c in terms of alpha so that f(c,alpha) >= 1.